# 既存のDBを用いてUserモデルの拡張を行いたい

Tags: python, mysql, django

### 既存のDBを用いて定義されたモデルクラスに関して、Userモデルの拡張を行いたい

##現状
既に使用されている　MySQLのDB情報をDjangoのDBとして使用しています。
初めにこのDB情報に関して、`settings.py`に書き込みました。

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_name', #　作成したデータベース名
        'USER': 'root', # ログインユーザー名
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password', # 同上。そのパスワード
    }
}
```

続いて、`python manage.py inspectdb >> my_app/models.py`を使用して、`models.py`に反映させました。
その結果、

```py
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
```

が作成されました。

この`user_id`を用いてログインの実装を行いたいです。
（フォームに入力があり、バックエンドでuser_idを元にログイン実装が行いたいです）

ログインにかかる`views.py`は下記のようになっています。

```py
class Account_login(View): #ログインテンプレート
    def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs): #POST時
        form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_id = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            user = User.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form,})

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): #GET時
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'accounts/login.html', {'form': form,})
```

この`user_id`を用いてログインの実装を行うためには、Userモデルの拡張が必要だと考えました。特に今回試みたのは、[こちら](https://hodalog.com/how-to-extend-django-user-model/)にあるような`models.OneToOneField`を使用しようと思い、

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
```

としました。これを踏まえて、`python manage.py runserver`を行うと

`src.User.user_id: (models.E006) The field 'user_id' clashes with the field 'user' from model 'src.user'.`
とエラーが返されました。`user_id`が`'user'`とクラッシュしているとのことで、このようなエラーが出ていると考えていますが、目的としては、既存のDBで定義された`user_id`をDjangoのログイン認証時のキーとしたいため、このエラーを乗り越えるため`user_id`を削除すると、目的が果たせません。上記の手法以外でも構いません。解決法やヒント、リンクなどで構いませんので、お力をお貸し下さい。よろしくお願いします。